# Possible to embed an iFrame within an A tag and have hover/links work?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a div that has an A tag wrapped around it's contents that works well for regular content but on one of the divs, there's a requirement to show an iframe from a stock source.

The problem that the iframe messes up the hover state and obviously the a tag doesn't really wrap or make the iframe a link.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Example HTML:

```html
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-9 ">
      <a href="http://www.apple.ca">
        <div class="ffb-imageContainer ffb-stock"></div>
        <div class="ffb-stockTitle">Company Name (TRP)</div>
        <div class="iframeWrapper">
          <iframe width="500" height="240" title="stock information" src="https://investor.shareholder.com/ctrp/includes/inc-iframe-stock-quote.cfm"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="ffb-textArea">4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectur dola cing elit, sed do eiusmod temular</div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: The hover state is important because...? What's the purpose of wrapping a link around an iframe? Is the link a button to reveal the iframe?

Comment: This box would be 1 of 4 boxes in the design that want all the same roll-over effect on the WHOLE area. i.e. http://www.kamunga.com/featureboxes.png    The Stock is an existing source from Nasdaq and it'd be easier to reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [specification says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The a element … Content model:
>   Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants

and it defines [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-2):

> a (if the href attribute is present) audio (if the controls attribute is present) button details embed **iframe** img (if the usemap attribute is present) input (if the type attribute is not in the Hidden state) label select textarea video (if the controls attribute is present)

… so no. You cannot have an iframe as a descendant of an anchor.